# background-color hiding before attribute in chrome android

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, background

I have a `:before` pseudo element attached to an li tag like this:

```
li.selected:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    margin-top: 0.9em;
    right: -0.9em;
    width: 1.7em;
    height: 1.7em;
    background-color: #ddd7d0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    box-shadow: -0.2em 0.4em 0.4em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0 0 0 0.6em transparent;
}
```

when I set a background-color to the li tag, the before hides and sometimed show up if I scroll the page.

What is wrong here?

Comment: please post the rest of the list definition + your html

Comment: Try adding `position: relative;` to the `li`